# ODEINT problems

Tags: python, odeint

I'm working in order to solve the differential equations of the standard model but I'm having problems. I wanted to know how to use the ODEINT function because it can solve my problems but sometimes I don't know how to interpret the graphs. I'm trying first to solve 3 diff equations and I can use a "t" vector from 0 to 100 with 100 points. After if I tried to solve the system with 9 equations more I have to use a vector "t" from -20 to 0.1 because python gives me this error:

> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
>     warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)

Could anyone please help me out?

Here is the code with the full equations:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy.integrate as spi
from numpy import loadtxt
from pylab import figure, plot, xlabel, grid, hold, legend, title, savefig
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


 #Units
 #eV=10**(-9);
 #MeV=10**(-3);
 #GeV=1;
 #TeV=1000 



escala= 0.0001
def vectorfield(w, t, p):
    """
    Defines the differential equations of the RGEs.

    Arguments:
        w :  vector of the state variables:
                  the variables
        t :  time
        p :  vector of the parameters:
                  the constants
    """
    g1, g2, g3, ye, ymu, yta, yu, yc, yt, yd, ys, yb = w
    b1, b2, b3 = p
    #T=ye**2 +ymu**2+yta**2+3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 +3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2                                                      
    # Create f = (g1',g2',g3',...,m2'):
    f = [b1*g1**3,
         b2*g2**3,
         b3*g3**3,
         ((3/2)*ye**3   +  ye*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2) -ye*((9/4)*g1**2 - (9/4)*g2**2)),
         ((3/2)*ymu**3  + ymu*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2) -ymu*((9/4)*g1**2 - (9/4)*g2**2)),
         ((3/2)*yta**3  + yta*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2) -yta*((9/4)*g1**2 - (9/4)*g2**2)),
         (3/2)*yu**3 - (3/2)*yu*yd**2 + yu*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2)  - yu*(8*g3**2 + (17/20)*g1**2 +(9/4)*g2**2),
         (3/2)*yc**3 - (3/2)*yc*ys**2 + yc*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2)  - yc*(8*g3**2 + (17/20)*g1**2 +(9/4)*g2**2),
         (3/2)*yt**3 - (3/2)*yt*yb**2 + yt*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2)  - yt*(8*g3**2 + (17/20)*g1**2 +(9/4)*g2**2),
         -(3/2)*yd*yu**2 + (3/2)*yd**3 + yd*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2)  - yd*(8*g3**2 + (9/4)*g2**2 +(1/4)*g1**2),
         -(3/2)*ys*yc**2 + (3/2)*ys**3 + ys*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2)  - ys*(8*g3**2 + (9/4)*g2**2 +(1/4)*g1**2),
         -(3/2)*yb*yt**2 + (3/2)*yb**3 + yb*(ye**2 + ymu**2 + yta**2 + 3*yc**2 + 3*yt**2 + 3*yd**2 + 3*ys**2 + 3*yb**2+ 3*yu**2)  - yb*(8*g3**2 + (9/4)*g2**2 +(1/4)*g1**2)]
    return f

b1 = 4.1
b2 = -3.1
b3= -7






g1=0.35
g2=0.65
g3=1.22
ye=(0.51*10**(-3))/174
ymu=(105.6*10**(-3))/174
yta=(1776*10**(-3))/174
yu=(2.3*10**(-3))/174
yc=1.29/174
yt=174/174
yd=(4.8*10**(-3))/174
ys=(95*10**(-3))/174
yb=4.18/174



abserr = 1.0e-8
relerr = 1.0e-6
stoptime = 0.1
numpoints = 250

scale=(16+stoptime)/249

t=np.linspace(0,100,100)
# Pack up the parameters and initial conditions:
p = [b1,b2,b3]
w0 = [g1, g2, g3, ye, ymu, yta, yu, yc, yt, yd, ys, yb]

wsol = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t, args=(p,),
              atol=abserr, rtol=relerr)




with open('data.dat', 'w') as f:
    # Print & save the solution.
    for t1, w1 in zip(t, wsol):
        print >> f, t1, w1[0], w1[1], w1[2], w1[3], w1[4], w1[5], w1[6], w1[7], w1[8], w1[9], w1[10], w1[11]

t, g1, g2, g3, ye, ymu, yta, yu, yc, yt, yd, ys, yb= loadtxt('data.dat', unpack=True)





figure(1, figsize=(6, 4.5))


xlabel('t')
grid(True)
lw = 1

plot(t, g1, 'b', linewidth=lw)
plot(t, g2, 'g', linewidth=lw)
plot(t, g3, 'm', linewidth=lw)
plot(t, yt, 'r', linewidth=lw)
plot(t, yb, 'y', linewidth=lw)
plt.show()
```